# how can I group by elements from one table and group by it by 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
table_id | user_id |   text   | number_id | start_time
1            1        gdsgds       8        2015-10-11 07:14:44
2            2        vcxvc        8        2015-10-11 07:20:44
3            4        ewgs         8        2015-10-12 09:19:22
4            7        vvvcc        8        2015-10-13 18:12:23
etc.
```

I need to write a query that will return me the number of texts displayed each day on each number. So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  DATEDIFF(now(), start_time) AS days_ago, 
            COUNT(table_id)             AS num_texts 
    FROM    TABLE 
    GROUP BY DATE(start_time)
) 
WHERE 
(
    days_ago <= 7 
AND days_ago > 0
)
```

and this query returns me a table:

```
days_ago  |  num_texts
   0      |     2
   1      |     3
   2      |     4
   3      |     1
```

and that works almost fine, but I need to divide it by number_id too... How can I do it?

Comment: So you want the output to be: `number_id | days_ago | num_texts` with same results that you show but adding the `number_id` column?

Comment: It would be better to do the `WHERE` in the subquery: `WHERE start_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()`

Comment: @Barmar thanks, can you tell me why it would be better?

Comment: Because it filters out rows before doing all the calculations and grouping. ALso, if you have an index on that column, it can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  DATEDIFF(now(), start_time) AS days_ago, 
            number_id, 
            COUNT(table_id)             AS num_texts 
    FROM    TABLE 
    GROUP BY DATE(start_time), number_id 
) 
WHERE 
    days_ago <= 7 
AND days_ago > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the column number_id to the select and group by in the subquery.