# I want to insert my json as a source to morris line chart and I need to parse it accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I'm using Morris.js library and I want to create a line chart from my json source. In my html code I included a simple div:

```
<div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
```

and currently I'm filling it with a dummy data:

```
Morris.Area({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [{
        period: '2010 Q1',
        iphone: 2666,
        ipad: null,
        itouch: 2647
    }, {
        period: '2010 Q2',
        iphone: 2778,
        ipad: 2294,
        itouch: 2441
    }, {
        period: '2010 Q3',
        iphone: 4912,
        ipad: 1969,
        itouch: 2501
    }, { ...
    }],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],
    labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

Now, I want to draw there six different lines on one chart. I created an sql query that comes from my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/33422796/4662074 and now the json that comes in looks like this:

```
[{"days_ago":null,"number_id":"1","num_texts":"9"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"1","num_texts":"179"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"5","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"17","number_id":"1","num_texts":"61"},
{"days_ago":"17","number_id":"2","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"17","number_id":"5","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"17","number_id":"6","num_texts":"3"},
{"days_ago":"16","number_id":"3","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"0","number_id":"1","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"0","number_id":"2","num_texts":"2"}, etc.]
```

I want to achieve an effect that each number_id is represented by a single line, on X axis we have days_ago value and on Y axis we have the number num_texts. Can you help me with parsing my json file accoridngly to this specs?